# Extract input value html and js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, onclick

Im trying to extract the values of my inputs. Im using this inputs in a JavaScript. Im using the onclick event on an input type button called thebutton and I want to extract the values in a function called data. The inputs are print in a div called formulary and I want to print the input values in a div called results. When I run it, the three values are print as undefined. So this is my current code:

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("fomulary").innerHTML+="<br>Data:<br><br>  <form><input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Name'<br><br><input id='address' type='text' placeholder='Address'<br> <br> <input id='tel' type='tel' placeholder='Phone number'><br> <input onclick='data()' type='button' id='thebutton' value='Send'></button> </form>";
     
      var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
      var address=document.getElementById("address").value;
      var tel=document.getElementById("tel").value;
    

function data(name, address, tel){

      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=name+" "+address+" "+tel;
      
    }
  
<script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You read the values when it is rendered. The value does not update. You need to read the values when you want the value. So the lines need to be in the function you call.

Comment: Thank you epascarello , It was a silly mistake, it works perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All the HTML elements will have attributes that stores some valuable information about that element. You can extract this information about the element using that array Nodelist under which there will be a key-value pair object.

To put it simply change

```
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
```

To

```
var name=document.getElementById("name")[0].value;
```

similarly apply this for all the other variables